# Checking Duplicate before Inserting

Tags: php

I am trying to check for duplicate data before inserting to the database, but, it still giving me errors, I have tried all my possible means, but I honestly don't know where I missed it

```
$dupesql = "SELECT * FROM table where (name = '$name' AND description = '$description' AND manufacturer = '$manufacturer' AND city ='$city' AND price = '$price' AND enddate = '$end_date')";

$duperaw = mysql_query($dupesql);

if (mysql_num_rows($duperaw) > 0)
```

but I keeping getting this result

> Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Empty query in C:\wamp\www\sug2019\form_processors\dgs_processor.php on line 52

Comment: `mysql_query` vs `Warning: mysqli_query()` something not right

Comment: tony you used `mysql_*` in your shown code, but you are getting error of `mysqli_*`? That's confusing. seems like you didn't show us complete/correct code as well as somewhere down the line you mixed the 2 libraries.

Comment: check [this](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/) may help!

Answer (score 2):

Try to solve your issue with `mysqli` instead of `mysql`

```
$dupesql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table where name = '$name' AND description = '$description' AND manufacturer = '$manufacturer' AND city ='$city' AND price = '$price' AND enddate = '$end_date'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($dupesql)<=0){
// No duplicate data found 
}else{
// Duplicate Data found
}
```

In this `$con` is your connection file variable

Comment: it didn't help sir

Comment: make sure your connection file is correct and also recheck your $_POST fields